# Transparent background SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, background-color, swiftui-list

I have a list in swiftUI and I want the background to be somewhat see through. However there seems to be a white background applied to both scrollview and List. I was wondering if anyone had a work around or way to change it so when .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7)) is applied to the list, it can be translucent and not have the same affect as .background(Color.white).

Here is my code for the view that I am trying to implement the desired effect. The wordPosts is simply just a custom data struct used to populate the list item data. I've already trying changing the cell and tableview appearance using UIkit on init which did not work.

```
struct ProfileWordsView: View {
    
    init(){
           UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
           UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
       }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(wordPosts) { post in
                Group {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack(alignment: .top) {
                            
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .fill()
                                .frame(width: 4)
                                
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                                    Text(post.title).font(.custom("Gilroy-SemiBold", size: 20)).foregroundColor(.black).lineLimit(1)
                                    Text("• \(post.timestamp)").font(.custom("Gilroy-SemiBold", size: 19)).foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                                HStack {
                                    Text(post.text).font(.custom("Gilroy-Regular", size: 16)).foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.7)).padding(.top, 5)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            VStack {
                                Button(action: {}) {
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 20, height: 15)
                                        .font(Font.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 6)
                                }
                                
                                Text("\(post.rizz)").font(.custom("Gilroy-SemiBold", size: 18)).foregroundColor(.gray)
                                
                                Button(action: {}) {
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 20, height: 15)
                                        .font(Font.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 5, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
                }.listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            }
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your view code. Please make sure to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible for your code but I'd recommend using a scrollview instead. They are transparent by default, so that should help. You can always add a frame with a semi-transparent color if you want to have a semi-transparent background instead.